Recovering localizable measure from null sets of localizable measurable space.
I have a problem with understanding how does the duality between categories of localizable measurable spaces and von Neumman algebras work.
To sum up:
A localizable measurable space is a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, equipped with a $\sigma-$ideal of null sets $\mathcal{I}$, such that for each family of measurable subsets, there exist its essential suppremum, that is a set in which each member of such family essentially contains. (by essentially contains I mean that for $E, F \in \mathcal{A},$ $E$ essentially contains $F$ if $\{x\in X: x \in F \land x \notin E\} \in \mathcal{I}$).
From what I know a localizable measurable space can admit only a localizable measure $\mu$. That is satisfying the following conditions:

For every $E \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(E)>0,$ $E$ essentially contains $F \in \mathcal{A}$, such that $\mu(F) < \infty.$
For every family $\{E_j\}_{j \in J} \subset \mathcal{A},$ there exist $E \in \mathcal{A}$, such that $E$ essentially contains each $E_j$ and for any $F \in \mathcal{A}$, such that $F$ essentially contains each $E_j$, we have that $F$ essentially contains $E.$ (Set $E$ is called an essential union of $\{E_j\}_{j \in J}$).

A localizable measure spaces have all desired properties e. g. for such a space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a topological dual $\big(L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu) \big)'$ is isomorphic as a Banach space to $L^\infty(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and also the Radon-Nikodym theorem holds.
Von Neumann algebras in this setting we understand not asbtractly: as a $*$-subalgebra $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{M}}$ of a C*-algebra $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}(\mathcal{H})$ of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ over a field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C},$ containing the identity operator $I$ and closed in weak operator topology.
By the results of Segal I think, we have a duality of the following categories

$\mathfrak{locmeas}$ - a category of localizable measurable spaces, where objects are localizable measurable spaces and morphism are classes of abstraction of measurable functions, considered up to null sets.
$\mathfrak{commvn}$ - a category of commutative von Neumann algebras, where objects are commutative von Neumann algebras and morphisms are $*-$homomorphism of a closed $*$-subalgebras of $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{B}}(\mathcal{H}),$ continuous in weak operator topology.

The functor acts by taking for a localizable measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{I})$ a space $L^\infty(X,\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{I})$. But here $L^\infty$ is considered as a multiplication operators on a Hilbert space $L^2.$ Norm on $L^\infty$ can be defined without a measure - only knowing the null sets. But I struggle tu understand how we obtain a measure to define $L^2(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$? Is it obtained somehow from predual of $L^\infty$ being $L^1$?
I would be grateful for some explanation.

Any localizable measure $\mu$ whose null sets are exactly $\mathcal{I}$ works. Any two such measures are absolutely continuous w.r.t. each other, so their $L^2$ spaces are unitarily equivalent through a unitary $u$ in such a way so that $ufu^\ast = f$ for every $f$ in $L^\infty$. (Use Radon-Nikodym derivative.)

Though, it’s really better to think in terms of abstract von Neumann algebras instead of concretely represented ones in this case, since that’s what makes the equivalence of categories work. Otherwise, you have to restrict to abelian von Neumann algebras in their standard form representations.


But I struggle tu understand how we obtain a measure to define L2(X,A,μ)?

You do not need a measure to define $L^2$, only a σ-ideal $I$ of negligible sets, as given in the definition of a localizable (enhanced) measurable space in the main post.
This can be most easily seen for the case of $L^1$, which is isomorphic to the space of finite measures via the Radon–Nikodym theorem.  The space of finite measures is defined without any reference to an arbitrary choice of a measure $μ$.
Now elements in $L^{1/p}$ can be defined as $p$th powers of elements in $L^1$: take equivalence classes of pairs $(f,μ)$ modulo the equivalence relation generated by $(f,gμ)=(fg^p,μ)$, with $g≥0$, taking $0^p=0$.  The pair $(f,μ)$ represents $fμ^p∈L^{1/p}$.
For more details, see the answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical/20820#20820.
As a side remark, the description of the category LocMeas as a “category of localizable measurable spaces, where objects are localizable measurable spaces and morphism are classes of abstraction of measurable functions, considered up to null sets” requires additional refinements, e.g., to compact strictly localizable enhanced measurable spaces, in order to get a category equivalent to commutative von Neumann algebras.  See the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.05284 for precise definitions and proofs.
